# Export from Excel to AccessDB, error Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ado

I try to export some data from excel to my access database, but on line 15 `rs.open` I get the error Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Public Sub updateAntibiotics(abName As String, Optional startDate As Date, Optional stopDate As Date)
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim currPath As String, DbPath As String
    Dim sProduct As String, sVariety As String, cPrice As Variant
    Dim patientID As Integer

    ' connect to the Access database
    currPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    DbPath = Left$(currPath, InStrRev(currPath, "\")) & "IZ Damiaan.accdb"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DbPath & "';"

    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "Antibiotics", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    patientID = Val(Sheets("PatientData").Range("A2"))

        rs.Filter = "fkPatientID='" & patientID & "' AND Antibiotic='" & abName & "' AND stopDate IS NULL"
        If rs.EOF Then
            Debug.Print "No existing record - adding new..."
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.AddNew
            rs("fkPatientID").Value = patientID
            rs("Antibiotic").Value = abName
        Else
            Debug.Print "Existing record found..."
        End If
        If Not IsNull(startDate) Then rs("startDate").Value = startDate
        If Not IsNull(stopDate) Then rs("stopDate").Value = stopDate
        rs.Update
        Debug.Print "...record update complete."

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Might just be a silly though, but I seem to remember seeing that error a lot if I left the database open in Access while attempting to connect in Excel..?

Comment: Closing the database gives the same error. And closing the database in the intended purpose of the application isn't realy an option...

Comment: I should also note that the table "Antibiotics" is a linked table from another database, but targeting the source gives the same error.

Comment: If you don't have a reference set to the ADO library, you need to either declare the constants you are using, or use their literal values.

Comment: I mean you need to declare these constants: `adOpenKeyset`, `adLockOptimistic`, `adCmdTable` or use their literal values (1, 3 and 2 respectively)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I still get the same error using the literal values

Comment: As stated by @Rory I declared the constants in the sub header (I found more info [here](http://keencode.blogspot.be/2014/01/vba-run-time-error-3001-arguments-are.html)), but the error stays the same.